# Find closest matching array element and group them

Tags: c#, grouping, quantum-computing

I would like to use qunatum computing for the below problem statement

There are list of arrays upto n

a1= [a,b,c,d,e]

a2= [a,b,d,e]

a3= [a,e]

a4=[a,e]

a5=[a,b,c,d,e]

The output should give the maximum common grouping items like, for a1 and a5 both are an exact match

a1 and a2 are matching except c and a3 a4 are exact match

so there can be one group which will give an output of exact match and close match which would be a1 a2 and a5 (they are having only 1 element in difference)

another group would be a3 and a4

How can we solve this in dynamic or qunatum computing

Comment: What is your criteria for a "close match"? Is it element based (i.e. two elements different is still "close enough") or is it percentage based (> 70% of items need to match)? -- Have a method or better yet an `IEqualityComparer<T>` that compares two elements. Then another one to calculate, if two sequences of elements are equal, close or too different. _Then_ the interesting part starts: sorting them into buckets. -- Assuming `[a], [a,b], [a,b,c]` and the "one item difference" rule: do you want to end up with trwo "close" groups both containing `[a,b]`, or do you need a seq to be in only one?

Comment: Does the sequence matter? Or is `[a,b,c]` and `[c,a,b]` an "exact match" for you?

Comment: No sequence is not an issue, also that percentage based we can use like if its matching more than 70% then calculate it as closed